# c# - Acess WebService - XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

i'm working with c#, and i'm new. 
I have a URL of a webservice: http://grillassessmentservice.cloudapp.net/GrillMenuService.svc

login: jobs@isolutions.ch

password: cleancode

that gives me that XML:

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"xml:base="http://grillassessmentservice.cloudapp.net/GrillMenuService.svc/">
 <workspace>
  <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
   <collection href="GrillMenus">
     <atom:title>GrillMenus</atom:title>
   </collection>
   <collection href="GrillMenuItemQuantities">
     <atom:title>GrillMenuItemQuantities</atom:title>
   </collection>
   <collection href="GrillMenuItems">
     <atom:title>GrillMenuItems</atom:title>
   </collection>
 </workspace>
</service>
```

I have that c# code in my console application:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://grillassessmentservice.cloudapp.net/GrillMenuService.svc");
        var serviceCreds = new NetworkCredential("foobar@outlook.com", "test");
        var cache = new CredentialCache();
        cache.Add(serviceUri, "Basic", serviceCreds);
        var service = new GrillMenu.GrillMenuContext(serviceUri)
        {
            Credentials = cache
        };
        foreach (var grillMenu in service.GrillMenus.Expand(g => g.GrillMenuItemQuantity))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu: {0}", grillMenu.Name);
            foreach (var grillMenuItemQuantity in grillMenu.GrillMenuItemQuantity)
            {
                service.LoadProperty(grillMenuItemQuantity, "GrillMenuItem");
                Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1}", grillMenuItemQuantity.Quantity,
                grillMenuItemQuantity.GrillMenuItem.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

But i can't access to web service. Someone can explain me how it works?
i tried to access by adding a reference, give me error on the login and password. On that stage:
[image]
Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a standard web service, it's a feed (Atom) type service that can be accessed via OData provider.
To add it, right-click on References, Add Service Reference Link (or similar), paste in http://grillassessmentservice.cloudapp.net/GrillMenuService.svc/.
Don't forget to add reference for System.Data.Services prior doing that - here's a full sample.

**Keep in mind you will need to enter credentials for EVERY sub-service so to say - after that it will work.**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Services.Client;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri grillUri =
                new Uri("http://grillassessmentservice.cloudapp.net/GrillMenuService.svc/",
                    UriKind.Absolute);
            ServiceReference1.GrillMenuContext context = new ServiceReference1.GrillMenuContext(grillUri);
            var serviceCreds = new NetworkCredential("jobs@isolutions.ch", "cleancode");
            var cache = new CredentialCache();
            cache.Add(grillUri, "Basic", serviceCreds);
            context.Credentials = serviceCreds;

            try
            {
                foreach (ServiceReference1.GrillMenuItem o in context.GrillMenuItems)
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", o.Name);                    
            }
            catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i add de references and the login and password, apeear that error:
`There was an error downloading 'http://grillassessmentservice.cloudapp.net/GrillMenuService.svc /$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://grillassessmentservice.cloudapp.net/GrillMenuService.svc'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic'.`